# Can not validate properly the radio button using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I cannot check the radio button select in my validation using JavaScript/jQuery. I am generating some multiple textarea, radio button and drop down list dynamically. My requirement is I will fill all field and check the validation. But it's not happening properly.

Here is my code:

```
function validate(){
    var x =document.getElementById('ques').value;
    console.log('value',x);
    for(var i=0;i<x;i++){
        var tid="questions"+ i;
        var rid='answer_type'+i;
        var sid="nscale"+i;
        var scaleid='#scaleid'+i;
        if(document.getElementById("questions"+ i)){
            if(document.getElementById(tid).value==''){
                alert('Please enter the question');
                return false;
            }else if($('input[id=answer_type' + i + ']').is(':checked')==false){
                alert('Please check the answer type');
                return false;
            }else if($(scaleid).css('display') == 'block'){
                  if(document.getElementById(sid).value==''){
                    alert('Please select the scale');
                    return false;

                  }
            }else{

            }
        }
    }
}
```

My complete code is here [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/r0iwvkt9x5bQWpXCcL5k?p=preview). My problem is when user has selected all radio button and also click on `validate` button still its displaying the alert message as `Please check the answer type`. My requirement is I will check all field and drop down list whether these are blank or not in validation case.

Comment: Note, you should not mix approaches. If you are using jQuery, don't do `document....`. Keep approach consistent.

Comment: Can you please make this correct in that same plunkr link.

Comment: The issue is in script when appending the radio button the id you have given to it is id="answer_type0"  but while validating you are looping the id's for radio button also.

Comment: @shubhamkhandelwal : Can you make this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and make the id of radio button in the addQuestionField() function as id="answer_type'+i+'" instead of id="answer_type0".